# Highcharts drilldown display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[Example drilldown fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/s5JqN/).

When you drilldown, you will notice sometimes the chart does not clear previous bars.

[image]

The drilldown data looks like this:

```
drilldown: {
            activeDataLabelStyle: {
                color: 'white',
                textShadow: '0 0 2px black, 0 0 2px black'
            },
            series: [{
                id: 'animals',
                name: 'Animals',
                data: [
                    ['Cats', 4],
                    ['Dogs', 2],
                    ['Cows', 1],
                    ['Sheep', 2],
                    ['Pigs', 1]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'fruits',
                name: 'Fruits',
                data: [
                    ['Apples', 4],
                    ['Oranges', 2]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'cars',
                name: 'Cars',
                data: [
                    ['Toyota', 4],
                    ['Opel', 2],
                    ['Volkswagen', 2]
                ]
            },{
                id: 'animals2',
                name: 'Animals2',
                data: [
                    ['Cats', 3],
                    ['Dogs', 5],
                    ['Cows', 6],
                    ['Sheep', 2],
                    ['Pigs', 2]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'fruits2',
                name: 'Fruits2',
                data: [
                    ['Apples', 1],
                    ['Oranges', 5]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'cars2',
                name: 'Cars2',
                data: [
                    ['Toyota', 2],
                    ['Opel', 3],
                    ['Volkswagen', 2]
                ]
            }]
        }
```

Comment: It is a bug which appeared yesterday in 5.0.4 version https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting behavior. Seems like a bug, cause their own examples are actually having the same issue. RC seems to be in animation. If you disable the animation for the drilldown, you will not see the residual series.

```
    drilldown: {
       animation:false,
       ...
    }
```